# time data 'May 10 2021' does not match format '%m %d %Y'

Tags: python, datetime, python-datetime

I am having trouble printing a formatted time object produced from a string

This is my code:

```
date_time_str = 'May 10 2021'
date_time_obj = datetime. strptime(date_time_str, '%m %d %Y')
print("The type of the date is now", type(date_time_obj))

This is the error:
ValueError: time data 'May 10 2021' does not match format '%m %d %Y'
```

Comment: From https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior: %m - Month as a zero-padded decimal number. You want %B - Month as locale’s full name.

Comment: @alkasm It still gives me this error - time data 'Jun 5 2021' does not match format '%B %d %Y'

Comment: Jun isn't the locale's full name. Directly below that table you'll see that %b is for the abbreviated name.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As per [This](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/datetime/strptime) link, for a month in the `Month` format, you need to use `%B` , and for a month in the `Mth` format ('Apr','Jun') , use `%b`.

You were using `%m`, which is used for numerical numbers.

The below works as an example:

```
import time
import datetime
from time import strptime
print("hello world")
date_time_str = 'May 10 2021'
date_time_obj = strptime(date_time_str, '%B %d %Y')
print("The type of the date is now", date_time_obj)
```

Comment: It still gives me this error - time data 'Jun 5 2021' does not match format '%B %d %Y' @StarshipladDev

Comment: @Shangx "Jun" is the *abbreviated* month name (in English). If you want to parse abbreviated month names, use `%b`.

Comment: @PM2Ring Haha I shouldn't have used an example with a 3-letter month! I have edited based on your reply, thank you

Comment: @Shangx could you answer this question as 'marked' if it solves you problem? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can also use datetime parser from `dateutil` package with fuzzy parsing which is extremely useful when parsing non-standard datetime formats or parsing dates from text:

```
from dateutil import parser as dps

>>> a = 'Today is 11th of June 2021'
>>> d = dps.parse(a, fuzzy=True)
>>> d
Out[5]: datetime.datetime(2021, 6, 11, 0, 0)

>>> b = 'May 10, 2021'
>>> c = dps.parse(b, fuzzy=True)
>>> c
Out[8]: datetime.datetime(2021, 5, 10, 0, 0)
```